# SQL 'After insert trigger' complains of unknown column 'currentId' in field list, which is cursor

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables.

```
create table comments (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    task_id int not null,
    foreign key fk_comment_task(task_id) references tasks(id),
    user int not null,
    foreign key fk_comment_user(user) references users(id),
    comment varchar(1000) not null,
    comment_date date not null,
    viewed tinyint(1) not null default 0,
    deleted tinyint(1) not null default 0   
) engine = InnoDB;
```

and a second one:

```
create table viewed_comments (
    id int auto_increment primary key,
    comment int not null,
    foreign key fk_viewed_comment(comment) references comments(id),
    viewer int not null,
    foreign key fk_viewed_viewer(viewer) references users(id),
    unread tinyint(1) not null default 0,
    deleted tinyint(1) not null default 0
) engine = InnoDB;
```

I want to create a trigger that says when a comment is inserted into the 'comments' table, the 'viewed_comments' table creates rows for that comment for all users except the one submitting the comment.

At the moment, I have a trigger:

```
delimiter |
create trigger ins_views after insert on comments 
for each row 
    begin
        DECLARE finished INT DEFAULT 0;
        DECLARE id INT DEFAULT 0;

        DECLARE currentId CURSOR FOR SELECT id FROM users WHERE id != NEW.user;

        DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER 
            FOR NOT FOUND SET finished = 1;

        OPEN currentId;

        update_views_loop: LOOP
            FETCH currentId INTO id;
            IF finished = 1 THEN LEAVE update_views_loop;

            END IF;
            INSERT INTO viewed_comments (comment, viewer) VALUES (NEW.id, currentId);   

        END LOOP update_views_loop;

     CLOSE currentId;

    END;
|

delimiter ;
```

When I do an insert into the such as 'insert into comments (task_id, user, comment, comment_date) values (24, 4, 'test', '2018-3-5'); as an example, I get the following response.
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'currentId' in 'field list' which is the cursor.  How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 INSERT INTO viewed_comments (comment, viewer) VALUES (NEW.id, id);
```

Because you read the value into the variable id. Use this value and not the cursor.

```
 FETCH currentId INTO id;
```